# How to close alerts in android activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, alerts

I'm trying to check internet connection in activity. And i'm using alerts to turn on **Wi-Fi** when there is no internet connection.

And I don't know what to do. My program makes 5 or more **alerts**.
What can I do to change it?

Comment: If your problem is that your code is producing too many alerts, show us that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check the Internet Connection the following method will be helpful. Alert Dialog will be called from in the if loop when there is no internet connection to activate the Wifi Connection.

```
public static void checkTheNetworkAvailability(Context con) {
        Context mycontext = con;
        ConnectivityManager myconnectivity = (ConnectivityManager) mycontext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (myconnectivity == null) {
            return false;
            // failed null!..
                    //show the alert box here for WiFi enabling
                    alert.show();
        } else {
            NetworkInfo[] myinfo = myconnectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (myinfo != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < myinfo.length; i++) {
                    if (myinfo[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

> The Alert Dialog will be  as follows

```
wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE); 
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Message")
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Wifi On", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

                    }
                });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Wifi Off", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

> And add the  below permissions in Manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Reuse the same `AlertDialog` instead of creating a new one each time the app has connection problems. You can use the `isShowing()` method for checking if the `AlertDialog` is being shown, so you don't need to show it again.